# Get my profile information after authentication

Tags: support, discussion

I am coding for a mobile application and using stack exchange API 2.1. I am able to implement oauth and I have access token also.

Now I am trying to retrieve my profile information, like user_id, name etc. using [/me](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me#order=desc&sort=reputation&filter=default&site=stackoverflow), I am passing my access token here in query string, but it seems to add a 'key' when I hit run.

What is that key and how would I get it for my phone app. I tried using client_secret and they app key they provide you register your app, doesn't seem to give me any response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app's key can be found by clicking "manage your applications" in the sidebar on the homepage of Stack Apps, then clicking the app's name.

Here's what the key looks like for the documentation console app:
[image]
<sub>`key` isn't secret, but `client_secret` is.</sub>

The console shoves it's own `key` value onto all requests *except* for the `/posts/{id}/comments/add` method (in general, write methods will follow this pattern).  This makes quick "get to know the API"-querying faster, but I guess it does make it a little trickier to start using your own app's keys.

To make a request using your own key, you can compose the query in the console, then copy it out of the url field:

[image]

Then you'll need to append your `access_token` and `key`.  Generally, once you're doing this a lot you should really be doing it in code.

Comment: and what benefit will I get if i append that key to query string? More number of requests?

Comment: @PiyushSardana The key is required when using an access_token (the console appends it's own key to requests when you "Get Token" with it [for GET's, POSTs require you enter your app's key & a paired access_token into the console]).  For non-authenticated requests all it gets you is a higher # of requests per day.